# How can I output the result of an API call in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a custom function that returns the result of an API call at the end - 'return result'.
The result is a string.

But how can I output this string in the Google Doc?

This is what I have tried so far, but without any result:

```
// Send the API request 
 var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())['choices'][0]['text']
 Logger.log(result)

  return result

  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph(result);
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like and what data do you want to input into the Google Doc and where in the Google Doc do you want it.?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are receiving a valid JSON as a response, I see 2 details in your code:

1. Comment out the **return result** line, as no code will be executed
   after a return statement.
2. You need to open the document by calling
   **DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();**

Your code should look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Send the API request 
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())['choices'][0]['text'];
  Logger.log(result)

  //return result;

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph(result);
}
```